# Recovering from damage on an implanted cyberdeck

Tags: skills, shadowrun-sr5

I have recently started playing SR5. My char, a decker, has an implanted cyberdeck.

On my last run, the implanted deck received some damage (not bricked, still able to work with). At the end, I did go to a clinic and got the device fixed for some nuyen.

Which skills should I have to fix an implanted deck?

I have Hardware, but nothing to take care of the "getting to an implanted device" part.

Answer (score 3):

You actually need Cybertechnology in order to repair the cyberdeck when its within a cyber limb. Check out page 144 in the core book for the full explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I checked this page, under Cybertechnology. However, my char does not have cyberlimbs. Would this apply without cyberlimbs?

Comment: From how i read it, its cyberware in general. So head ware, bodyware and the likes. Now...the feasibility of someone doing repair in a strange bending situations or situations where you can't see could pull some dice from your pool. That being said, it believe it still falls firmly under that skill category.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a toolbox and some spare time, even if the device was bricked.

On the core rulebook, page 228:

> **Repairing Matrix Damage**
>   If you have a device with Matrix damage, you can repair
>   it with a toolkit, an hour of work, and a Hardware
>   + Logic [Mental] test. Every hit you get can be used
>   to either remove one box of Matrix damage or cut the
>   time required in half; the first die spent toward time reduces
>   the time to half an hour, the second to 15 minutes,
>   and so on, to a minimum of one Combat Turn (3
>   seconds).
>
> Bricked or not, the device is off-line and unusable
>   during the repair process.
>   If you critically glitch on the roll to repair your device,
>   that’s it. The device is permanently bricked. You can use
>   it as a paperweight, an object lesson, or (if you need
>   one) a brick. If you glitch, the device can be restored to
>   functionality, but it becomes a bit glitchy (the gamemaster
>   will tell you how at an appropriate moment).

Implanted cyberdecks should be easily accessible, otherwise there is no point in implanting them, you will just have to spend thousands of nuyen on shadow clinics every time out get out of a cyber combat.

This issue is further discussed [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Shadowrun/comments/2asn4g/5e_repairing_implanted_cyberdecks/), [on shadowrun's forums](http://shadowrun.com/forums/discussion/34513/a-couple-of-cyberdeck-questions), and [on dumpshock's forums](http://forums.dumpshock.com/index.php?showtopic=39350).

Aaron gave us this answer on dumbshock forums:

> I think it will eventually be made clear that cyberware has one or more **external ports for maintenance**.

But basically, you will need either a datajack to access your cyberdeck, otherwise you cannot even manually reboot it as you would need to split your body open to reach his on/off button. Or follow the description given by Drake Noble on SR's forum:

> As for repairing matrix damage - implanted devices that need repairs (or upgrades) like a commlink or a cyberdeck are actually (according to Shadowrun back when they actually told or showed you this stuff clearly enough - so SR1 & 2) installed on a "plate" attached to the outside of, or replacing a section of, the skull... which means the parts that need repairs to clear up matrix damage are actually close to the skin.

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot of possibilities, but no clarification from the rulebooks, if I understood. I will have to discuss this with the GM.